# Rescale linear interval [a, b] to logarithmic [0, 1] scale in stead of linear [0, 1] (normalization)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, logarithms, python

I can't get my head around this simple problem. I would very much appreciate a good explanation in the answers.

I have a data array in which elements are between `[a, b]` and I normalize this array between `[0, 1]` using:

```
min_scale = np.min(data)
max_scale = np.max(data)
normalized_data = (data - min_scale) / (max_scale - min_scale)
```

Instead of normalizing to a linear `[0, 1]` scale, I would like to normalize to a logarithmic scale between `[0, 1]` in order to increase the importance of values closer to the max and decrease the importance of values closer to the minimum.

I am still looking for a convincing formula.. Does it make sense to first linearly normalize `[a, b]` to `[1, e]` and then take the `log` of the resulting vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested transformation seems fine. You could add a degree of freedom by first linearly transforming $[a,b] \to [1,\theta]$ followed by $\log_\theta$. This gives the transformation

$$x \mapsto \frac{\ln  \left(\frac{a \theta -b}{a-b}+\frac{(1-\theta ) x}{a-b}\right)}{ \ln (\theta) }. $$

Comment: Thank you. I now realize (through a few plots with your transformation) that I can either boost all values towards 1 or nerf all values towards 0 but not both as I first thought visually by looking at a log scale. With the transformation you gave, all values are boosted towards 1; and the boost strength is increased by increasing theta.

Comment: @Mathieu Maybe $\tanh$ (scaled & shifted) will do what you want.

Comment: @PM2Ring As you probably notice, despite the transformation given by user1337 doing what I described, it is not the result I was expecting. Maybe tanh might be it, could you add the transformation with its expression as a separate answer please?